# Self Join in Linq with null values c#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, self-join

How can i get the rows that have null in the column used for self join ?
My code is :

```
IEnumerable<ListClassView> list = from l in lists join lp in lists on 
l.ParentListId equals lp.Id 
select new ListClassView()
{
    Id = l.Id,
    ListName = l.ListName,
    Description = l.Description,
    ParentName = lp.ListName,
    IsActive = l.IsActive
};
```

I am unable to fetch rows where `ParentListId=null`. Is there a way where i can get all rows ?

Comment: Are you looking for a [left join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx)?

Comment: Yes :) I just found the way of doing this with left join in linq. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [from here](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/c-left-outer-joins-with-linq) by applying a left join :

```
IEnumerable<ListClassView> list = from l in lists join lp in lists on 
l.ParentListId equals lp.Id into lpp
from p in lpp.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new ListClassView()
{
    Id = l.Id,
    ListName = l.ListName,
    Description = l.Description,
    ParentName = p.ListName,
    IsActive = l.IsActive
};
```

Now, It gets all rows including those with `ParentListId = null`

Answer (score 1):

Alternative syntax:

```
var list = lists.GroupJoin(
  lists,
  l => l.ParentListId,
  lp => lp.Id,
  (l, lp) => new ListClassView
            { 
               Id = l.Id, 
               ListName = l.ListName, 
               Description = l.Description,
               ParentName = lp.FirstOrDefault() == null ? null : lp.First().ListName,
               IsActive = l.IsActive
            });
```